# Link is cut off after quotation in php

Tags: php, html, forms

When I have a form like this one -

```
<form action="t.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="test"></input>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Processed by PHP like this -

```
<?php
    $t = $_GET["test"];
    echo "<a href='".$t."'>".$t."</a>";
?>
```

If I provide an form input like -

> What's a form?

The link is cut off after "What". I know this is because of the quotation mark, but I'm not sure how to get around it in a way that would deal with any number of single or double quotation marks.

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "<a href='".urlencode($t)."'>".$t."</a>";
```

To play safe, you should cater `htmlspecialchars` to protect yourself from xss or so

`htmlspecialchars`

```
echo "<a href='".urlencode(htmlspecialchars($t), ENT_QUOTES))."'>".$t."</a>";
_________________^ cater for question mark which not able to convert
```

Comment: He do not need `urldecode()`, since it is performed automatically by php. But he **do need** `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: You know you can edit your answer? ;) (replace urlencode with htmlspecialchars)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use addslashes() and stripslashes().